# Simple/elegant way to do object to object transformation in Java?

Tags: java

I have to take over and improve/finish some code that transforms Java objects from a third party library into internal objects. Currently this is done through a big if-else statement along the lines of:

```
if (obj instanceOf X)
{
    //code to initialize internal object
}
else if (obj instanceOf Y)
{
    //code to initialize different object
}
else if (obj instanceOf Z)
{
    //more init code
}
...
```

Personally I don't find this solution satisfactory; it's long and messy and to make matters worse many of the if-else blocks contain more if-else blocks dealing with subclasses and edge cases. Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Possibly, but without a bit more information about the objects you're getting and the kind of initialisation you're doing based off them, it's hard to tell - this is one of those "it depends" answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an interface like this

```
public interface Converter<S,T> {
  public T convert(S source);
}
```

and implement it for each object of X,Y,Z. Then put all known converters into a Map and get happy!

Comment: That doesn't really help because generic types are static so you'd still have to do a bunch of instanceof's to use the correct Convert instance.

Comment: You stick the Converters in a Map keyed by its class type.

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't work for edge cases, building a Map between Classes and Converters

X.getClass() -> X Converter
Y.getClass() -> Y Converter

would get you a lot closer.  You'd want to also check superclasses if the leaf class is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Code like this, with all of its `instanceof` conditions, screams for an interface!

You may want to create a `public interface Initializable`, with a method `public void initialize()`.

Then all if your if-else's simply resolve into a single `obj.initialize()` call.

Answer (score 0):

If these internal objects present an interface to the application, rather than being used directly, adapt them rather than converting them.

That is, if you have something like this:

```
public class ThirdPartyClass { ... }
public interface InternalInterface { ... }
public class InternalClass { ... }

Internal foo(ThirdPartyClass thirdParty) {
    InternalClass internal = new InternalClass();
    // convert thirdPaty -> internal
    return internal;
}
```

Then instead do something like this:

```
public class ThirdPartyClass { ... }
public interface InternalInterface { ... }
public class InternalClass { ... }

public class ThirdPartyInternalAdapter implements InternalInterface {
    private final ThirdPartyClass thirdParty;
    public ThirdPartyInternalAdapter(ThirdPartyClass thirdParty) {
        this.thirdParty = thirdParty;
    }
    // implement interface in terms of thirdParty
}
```

It's not clear from your question if this applies, but if it does this may be easier and more efficient than direct object-to-object conversion.